# How to trigger a hook by pressing a button in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I'm making an app using React Native and facing a problem while making a countdown timer.

I needed to use setInterval in order to implement this, but I found that setInterval will not act what I have expected.

So I used custom Hooks from [this post](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/), and here's the code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  // Remember the latest callback.
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // Set up the interval.
  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
}
```

After that, I made a button to make a timer to be triggered:

```js
const [leftTime, setTime] = useState(300000);
const triggerTimer = () => {
  useInterval(() => setTime(leftTime - 1), 1000);
};

return (
  <>
    <Text>{leftTime}</Text>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => triggerTimer()}
      <Text>Start Countdown!</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </>
);
```

However, I got an error saying 'Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.'

I already know that Hooks must be called at the very top of the function component, but is there any way to trigger a hook by pressing a button in the app?

Also, I want to stop the timer automatically and do something after that when the state 'leftTime' becomes 0.

Comment: what is wrapping the second part? what you mean after that?

Comment: @elirand5 I wrote the function 'useInterval' as a separate file and imported it into the component.